# fs write returns 0 bytes written

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs

So I'm trying to write a buffer to a file. I'm using the `fs.write` to make it happen, but things are acting up.

```
fs.write(info.fd, myBuffer, null, null, function(err, written, buffer)     {
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    console.log(written);
    console.log(buffer);
    fs.close(info.fd, function(err) {
          if (err) {console.log(err);}
    });
});
```

So, the `console.log(written)` prints out `0`, even though the `console.log(buffer)` prints out `<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a 0a 63 68 61 6e 67 65 0a>`. Does anyone know what could be going on here? Everything else seems to be working, so I don't really know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'fs.write' function has 2 forms:

```
fs.write(fd, buffer, offset, length[, position], callback)
fs.write(fd, data[, position[, encoding]], callback)
```

It would appear that your call is matching the first form and using `null` as the length to write.

You might try passing the length of the buffer if you intend to write it all:

```
fs.write(info.fd, myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.length, function(err, written, buffer)     {
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I thought those were optional parameters